# 9650SE RAID inoperable

Tags: raid, hard-drive, 3ware

While Rebuilding a RAID 5 array, one of the other drives in the array failed and the array iss now showing as Raid Inoperable. the 2nd drive that failed is now showing in the available drives list as working, but is no longer part of the raid. which means the raid is still unavailable. is there a way to re add this drive so i can finsih the re-build.

its a RAID 5 with 8 Drives on a 3ware 9650SE

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I'd trust it to complete the rebuild. Either the controller has an issue or the drive has something bad.

I'd get two new drives and restore from backup, personally.

Even if you could pull data on it, unless there's damage that can repaired it may be in a format just for the card to read from for that array. You'd get crud from the drive outside its array structure.

If your manufacturer doesn't have any utilities meant to repair a situation like this, they'll most likely tell you to reformat the volume and restore from backup.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have a backup. the logical drive was unmounted at the time of the rebuild. so im hopeing there wasnt any writes to the array.  in the raid error log its showing: Primary DCB read error occurred: port=6, error=0x202. which is the drive thats now showing in the available list

Comment: No backup? why not? I'd be very surprised if this data is recoverable at all.

Comment: Whatever the value of your lost data, think of it as a sunk cost in learning to take backups.

Comment: @Chopper3 & Chris S: i dont have a backup because its my home Box and there isnt a cheap way to backup 6+ TB that i know of. 

Is there no way to even try to repair the array? the data isnt that valueable, its just stuff ive collected over the years and id prefer not to lose it.

Comment: Probably not but given this is just home use stuff it should be on our sister site superuser.com (have a quick read of the FAQ some time please).

Comment: @chopper3 I've got a RAID5 on an AMD platform w/ backup.  However, lets just say I didn't have backup. Which wears on the drives more, a) doing a from-scratch backup of the drives, or b) resyncing the RAID array?

Comment: @Rolnik, restoring from backup is more wear-n-tear on the drives. But that's beside the point. RAID != Backup. **It *decreases* the chances of lost data; it does not *eliminate* the chances**. And with drives getting larger, the chances of being unable to resync an array increase.

Comment: It's not actually a backup because backups restore data temporally. I.e., in a RAID, when a user deletes a document accidentally, RAID will not recover it. Backups do. RAID increases availability, so your system is "available" despite drive (hardware) failure.